# Login Screen wants to be on the same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a login screen using Bootstrap.

But the login box not in a row, I have tried alot for to set it up , but i am not able to do that

and i am not able to find how to change the colors of list item

anybody's help appreciated.

```
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="edutechonline.servlets.SessionFilter,      edutechonline.database.*"%>   
  <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
  <%@taglib prefix="edutech" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

 <%
    try {
        int userId=SessionFilter.getUserId(request);
        boolean loggedIn=false;
        //if the ID was valid
        if (userId>=0) {
            loggedIn=true;

            request.setAttribute("user", Users.getUser(userId));
        }
        request.setAttribute("loggedIn", loggedIn);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "error loading page");
    }


 %>
 <edutech:template title="home" css="public/home" js="">

<title>Edutechonline</title>

    <div id="whatsNew" class="mainbox col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h5 class="panel-title">What's New</h5>
            </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
            <li>New course on Linux- Introduction to Linux</li>
            <li>New courses on Verification - Formal methods in software engineering.</li>
            <li>Trouble in finding the formula in Microsoft excel- Excel in Microsoft excel</li>
            <li>Interested in photoediting !!- Introduction to adobe photoshop</li>
            <li>Website designing - Introduction to HTML and CSS</li>
            <li>New course on Animation</li>


        </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="container"> 
<c:if test="${!loggedIn}">
  <form method="POST" action="j_security_check">

        <div id="loginDiv" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 "> 
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                 <div class="panel-heading">
                <h5 class="panel-title">Login</h5>
            </div>
                     <div class="panel-body">



                        <div style="padding-top:10px" class="panel-body" >

                                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="uname" value="" placeholder="username or email">                                        
                                    </div>

                                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                        <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" value="" placeholder="password">
                                    </div>



                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">

                                        <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                            <a id="btn-login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</a>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12 control">
                                            <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%" >
                                                        Not yet Registered! 
                                                <a href="/EduTechOnline/jsp/public/registration.jsp">
                                                        Sign Up Here
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>    

                        </div>
                </div>                     
            </div> 
        </div>
    </form>
 </c:if> 


        <c:if test="${loggedIn}">
            <p>Hello, ${user.getFullName()}</p>
            <p><a onclick="javascript:logout();">logout</a></p>
        </c:if>
    </div>


</edutech:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you're using bootstrap and want to use inline forms so that your inputs are all on one row, you need to use bootstrap's classes and dom structure.

```css
.form-inline .form-group {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="form-inline" role="form" _lpchecked="1">
  <div class="form-group username">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
      <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group password">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
</form>
```